# Instrinsic definition of concave and convex polyhedron

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, polyhedra, solid-geometry, solid-angle

Is it possible to distinguish a concave polyhedron from a convex one by mesurements made only on its surface, without a reference to the 3d space around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Consider (a) a pyramid atop a cube (convex), and (b) a cube with a pyramidal piece cut out of one face (not convex).  As intrinsic surfaces, these are isometric.

[image]

Comment: I thought so, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, any polyhedron, subtending a solid angle $\Omega<2\pi$ sr at each of its vertices, is called a convex polyhedron.

While any polyhedron, subtending a solid angle $\Omega>2\pi$ sr at any of its vertices, is called a concave polyhedron.

It is very practical that a convex polyhedron has its each vertex elevated (protruding outward) while a concave polyhedron has any of its vertices indented on the surface.